# VBA Excel Do While Statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop, do-while

I am trying to determine run time of equipment in a shift which is output in the following form;

```
    27/01/2016 18:00:00         4
    28/01/2016 6:00:00         12
    28/01/2016 18:00:00         4
    29/01/2016 6:00:00          0
```

The Macro aims to loop down columns and recording the start time and end time of shifts i.e

```
    28/01/2016 02:00 to 28/01/2016 22:00:00.
```

If there is a zero after the block is composed of the consecutive hours.

However if there is a gap in time like below the second 4 hour becomes an individual block:

```
    27/01/2016 18:00:00         4
    28/01/2016 6:00:00         12
    28/01/2016 18:00:00         0
    29/01/2016 6:00:00          4
```

My current code looks like the following

```
  Sub EX01()

Dim ColCount As Long
Dim startrow, endrow As Long
Dim i, j As Long
Dim nextRow As Long
Dim Cumm As Double


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("XACT RE")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("RE_EX 01")

ws.Select




startrow = Cells(1, 2).Value
endrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
Cells(1, 28) = startrow
Cells(1, 29) = endrow

nextRow = 2 'this is the row to put info on RE sheet

For j = 3 To 6
For i = startrow To endrow

    Cumm = 0
    If Cells(i, j) <> 0 Then

        'this is the inital pickup row
            ws3.Cells(nextRow, 1) = ws.Cells(i + 1, 2) - (ws.Cells(i, j).Value / 24) 'get next row time and subtract the hours in this cell
            ws3.Cells(nextRow, 3) = ws.Cells(3, j)
            Cumm = Cumm + ws.Cells(i, j).Value

            'now check how long the run goes for and add the delay data to Cumm
        Do While Cells(i + 1, j).Value >= 12
                        i = i + 1
            Cumm = Cumm + ws.Cells(i, j).Value


        Loop

        'this exits loop if less than 10
        ws3.Cells(nextRow, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value + ((ws.Cells(i, j).Value) * (0.5 / 12))
        ws3.Cells(nextRow, 8) = Cumm
        nextRow = nextRow + 1


    End If



  Next i
 Next j




End Sub
```

So My Question is how do I account for single shifts less than 12 hours and how do I account for small shifts (less than 12) that occur following a 12 hour shift....

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Gareth I have Edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am not too good in this, so I will just adapt the things I saw right away. But first: in which column is the start-date/time, in which is the end-date/time? Is it all in the same column?

```
Sub EX01()

Dim ColCount As Long    
Dim startrow As Long
Dim endrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim nextRow As Long
Dim Cumm As Double
```

I believe it's an old practice to declare variables on 1 line only. Also I think it's not a good habbit. If I am correct this is just the better way to keep track of all the variables that are used.

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("XACT RE")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("RE_EX 01")

ws.Activate
```

I recently learned that .select is never a good idea, try workaround!

```
'startrow = Cells(1, 2).Value
'endrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
'Cells(1, 28) = startrow
```

Is it correct, that you want to enter the value of Cell(B1) into Cell(AB1)?? if yes try this instead:

```
ws.Cells(1,28).Value = ws.Cells(1,2).Value
'Cells(1, 29) = endrow

startrow = ws.Rows(1)
endrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row  'this will give you the last entry on this worksheet

'nextRow = 2
```

This will always stay 2 I believe what you want is this:

```
nextRow = (ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row) + 1

For j = 3 To 6
    For i = startrow To endrow
        ws3.Cells(nextRow, 1) = ws.Cells(i + 1, 2) - (ws.Cells(i, j).Value / 24) 'get next row time and subtract the hours in this cell
        ws3.Cells(nextRow, 3) = ws.Cells(3, j)
        Cumm = Cumm + ws.Cells(i, j).Value
```

Do you want to print Cumm somewhere? otherwise this will just run through...
Also you're already doing this 1 line in code up!

```
        Do While ws.Cells(i + 1, j).Value >= 12
            i = i + 1
            Cumm = Cumm + ws.Cells(i, j).Value
        Loop
```

The loop will exit, as soon as in the next row of the searched cell there is a value of "12"

```
        ws3.Cells(nextRow, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value + ((ws.Cells(i, j).Value) * (0.5 / 12))
        ws3.Cells(nextRow, 8) = Cumm
        nextRow = nextRow + 1

    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Also ALWAYS be very specific from which worksheet you're adressing the cells. With a little more info I might help you a little better :)